# MATLAB FFT plotting

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, matlab-figure

How do I plot the x-axis of the FFT plot? I have the amplitude down, but the x-axis is giving me a hard time. Also, my magnitude is mirrored. How would I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

An `N`-point DFT of a discrete-time signal with sampling frequency `fs` gives frequencies `0`, `1/fs`, ..., `(N-1)/fs`. To have the zero frequency in the center of the plot you can apply [`fftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to the DFT result, and then define the frequencies as `( -N/2:N/2-1 )/N*fs` for `N` even, or `( -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2 )/N*fs` for `N` odd (this exploits the periodicity of the DFT).

#### Example

Signal formed by two sinusoids of different frequencies and amplitudes.

```
N = 400;
fs = 1000; % Hz
fc1 = 120; % Hz
fc2 = 260; % Hz
y = sin(2*pi*fc1*(0:N-1)/fs) + .5*sin(2*pi*fc2*(0:N-1)/fs); % example signal
Y = fft(y);
if ~mod(N,2) % even
    f_axis = ( -N/2:N/2-1 )/N*fs;
else % odd
    f_axis = ( -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2 )/N*fs;
end
plot(f_axis, fftshift(abs(Y)));
grid
```

[image]